# drawing a line without coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a line that goes through a point A en B but does not stop at A nor at B. Can anybody help.
I want to use it for constructions in optics.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[very thin, dotted, color=gray,step= 0.5 cm] (-12.1,-5.1) grid (12.1,5.1);
  \draw (-12.1,0) -- (12.1,0) ;
  \draw [<->, ultra thick] (0,-3.2) -- (0,3.2) ;
  \coordinate (L1) at (0,3);
  \coordinate (L2) at (0,-3);
  \coordinate (L3) at (0,1.5); %evenwijdig met hoofdas
  \coordinate (V1) at (9,0);
  \coordinate (V2) at (9,1.5);
  \coordinate (F1) at (4,0);
  \coordinate (F2) at (-4,0);
  \draw [->, thick] (V1) -- (V2) node[right] {voorwerp};
  \fill (F1) circle (2pt) node[below] {$f_1$};
  \fill (F2) circle (2pt) node[below] {$f_2$};
  \draw [name path=A--B] (V2) -- (L3);
  \draw [name path=C--D] (L1) -- (L2);
  \path [name intersections={of=A--B and C--D,by=E}];
  \node [fill=red,inner sep=1pt,label=-90:$E$] at (E) {};
  \draw [name path=K--L] (E) -- (F2);
  \line(4,2){6};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see where A or B are defined in your code.  Which line is it that you are trying to draw?  How far beyond the points do you want it to extend - is it a known distance or some proportion of the distance between them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

an alternative that I like to use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (1,0) node[label=above:a,circle,fill=green,](a){} -- 
      (3,2)node[label=above:b,circle,fill=green,](b){} 
      coordinate[pos=1.5](ff) 
      coordinate[pos=-0.5](dd);
\draw (dd) -- (ff);
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Using [pos = xx] to place a point ( node or coordinates) as well as between the two points at the segment beyond. Negative values ​​are used to place the point before the first.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Here's one possibility using the `<coord>!<number>!<coord>` syntax; the line will extend past both coordinates by 1cm:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,fill=green,label=left:a] (a) at (1,0) {};
\node[circle,fill=green,label=left:b] (b) at (3,2) {};
\draw[blue] ($ (a)!-1cm!(b) $) -- ($ (b)!-1cm!(a) $);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Sections **13.5.3 The Syntax of Partway Modifiers** and **13.5.4 The Syntax of Distance Modifiers** of the `pgfmanual` contain the description of useful operations involving coordinates.

The shorten option gives another simpler alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,fill=green,label=left:a] (a) at (1,0) {};
\node[circle,fill=green,label=left:b] (b) at (3,2) {};
\node[circle,fill=green,label=left:c] (c) at (5,2) {};
\node[circle,fill=green,label=left:d] (d) at (7,0) {};
\draw[blue,shorten >=-1cm,shorten <=-1cm] (a) -- (b);
\draw[red,shorten >=-2cm,shorten <=-1cm] (c) -- (d);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First possibility can be simpler: `\draw[blue] ($(a)!-1cm!(b)$) -- ($(b)!-1cm!(a)$);`

Comment: @PaulGaborit yes, of course. I updated my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Ok... But you forgot to remove the call to `let`! ;-)  I corrected myself.

Answer (score 4):

A PSTricks solution just for comparison purpose.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](5,5)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={90}]
        (2,2){A}
        (3,3){B}
    \pstLineAB[nodesep=-1,linecolor=red]{A}{B}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

We can use `nodesepA` and `nodesepB` instead of `nodesep` if we want to have asymmetric line extension.

Comment: Why did you answer as cw?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: To avoid getting reputation points.

Comment: I am confused! I think your answer is legitimate to show an alternative.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: :-)